# How do I run a cronjob from cron.d?

Tags: postgresql, cron

I created a file called 'test_purge' in /etc/cron.d that contains:

```
00 04 * * * postgres /var/lib/pgsql/test.sh
```

This is supposed to run test.sh at 4 AM everyday, right?

test.sh has:

```
#!/bin/bash
psql -d kettle -c "TRUNCATE TABLE test;"
```

Am I supposed to do anything else to make this run? Do I add 'test_purge' which is in cron.d to my crontab or anything? I tried to run it last night but it did not work.

Comment: Use `crontab -e` to add to your cron. Also, make sure postgres user has permissions to execute the script. If `test.sh` does not have a header with `#!/bin/sh`, then you should add `postgres /bin/sh /var/lib...`

Comment: You don't typically use `crontab -e` for global crontab entries. It broadly looks ok, although obviously test.sh isn't a valid shell-script just by itself.

Comment: Just in case anybody else runs up against this, my problem was dots in the filename, which are not allowed. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cron/+bug/706565

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `cron` file and scripts seems correct. There some things to test though.

First, make sure you script has execution permission (specially for `postgres` user):

```
$ chmod +x /var/lib/pgsql/test.sh
```

I'd also set it to `postgres` user as owner:

```
$ chown postgres:postgres /var/lib/pgsql/test.sh
```

Now. Make sure the `psql` binary is mapped in your `PATH` environment, for a `cron` file you have to set the `PATH` into the file:

```
PATH=/usr/lib/pgsql/bin:/usr/local/bin/:/usr/bin/:...
00 04 * * * postgres /var/lib/pgsql/test.sh
```

At last, make sure you can see the script output somehow, either by checking the user mail or by redirecting the outputs to a file, e.g.:

```
00 04 * * * postgres /var/lib/pgsql/test.sh > /tmp/test.log 2>&1
```